# Need to send <div> content from one page to a specific <div> of another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am attempting to create a drag-and-drop slide show builder. So far, it's been going pretty well. The user selects their slide, then drags and drops it into an area designated for it. The drag and drop script loads the contents into a "div" tag on the page right in an ordered list.

This is my everything. It completes me. I need this content...to be sent to another page...

...and it's been EPIC FAIL so far.

I am attempting to take the contents of the "div" (which add "li" with the Item's info that is so important to me), and send them to another page where the selected data will be the basis of the slide show.

A "div to div" script is what is making me pull my hair out!

((NOTE: I started a session but have no idea how to use it))
((NOTE: I am a beginner when it comes to PHP, most of my experience is in front-end development. Please be gentle.))
((NOTE: No, I haven't started drinking. Yet. I am attempting humor. We'll see how it goes.))

What follows is the code on the original page "NEW16":

```
    <?php
session_start( );
session_register('cart');
session_register ('drop');
include 'canvas.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Presentation Builder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="htmldemodraganddrop.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- icons from  http://www.iconfinder.net/search/?q=iconset:superpack | author site : http://officinadigitale.forumcommunity.net/-->
    <ul id="products">
        <li><a class="item" href="#" id="2020Vision" draggable="true"><img src="2020Vision.jpg" /><div><p><strong>2020 Vision</strong></p><p><strong></strong>: <span></span></p></div></a></li>
        <li><a class="item" href="#" id="3000Days" draggable="true"><img src="3000Days.jpg" /><div><p><strong>3000 Days</strong></p><p><strong></strong>: <span></span></p></div></a></li>
        <li><a class="item" href="#" id="3000Days-Economictrends" draggable="true"><img src="3000Days-Economictrends.jpg" /><div><p><strong>3000 Days-Economic trends</strong></p><p><strong></strong>: <span></span></p></div></a></li>
        <li><a class="item" href="#" id="401Kor401G" draggable="true"><img src="401Kor401G.jpg" /><div><p><strong>401K or 401G</strong></p><p><strong></strong>: <span></span></p></div></a></li>
        <li><a class="item" href="#" id="AccumulationCalculator" draggable="true"><img src="AccumulationCalculator.jpg" /><div><p><strong>Accumulation Calculator</strong></p><p><strong></strong>: <span></span></p></div></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="cart">
        <form method="post" action="canvas.php?content=cart">
            <input type="hidden" name="cart" value="<?php echo $cart; ?>" />
        <h1>Slide Builder</h1>
        <ul></ul>
        <h2>Drop here to add Slide</h2>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
    </div>      
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ndd.js"></script>
    <script src="jsdemodraganddrop.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the "Slide Builder," between the UL tags are where the content that contains IDs goes when a user drops it in. I want the name of the file chosen, and a relative link to the full size image included, and nothing else to populate the "canvas.php" page.

So I'm thinking that I'm pretty slick over here. And that's where I run right into that big brick wall of fate. "NEW16" right now loads the images. They have mouse-over titles, users can drag them into the cart, and the cart total updates with the name of the file. I have put it (probably clumsily) into a form to be submitted. I can't seem to get any content from one page to the next.

(Hangs head in shame)

And here's why: The code for "canvas.php"

```
<?php  session_start(); 
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php Print_r ($cart); echo "<p>"; ?>
DIV Content<?php echo $_PRODUCT["id"]; ?>

<?php echo $cart; 
echo $_POST['cart'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is so woefully inadequate and I should be banished from the interwebs. I know. That's why I am here. Usually, I get my answers by searching and never have to post (thank you). This time, I need to ask for help.

I just need to send the cart contents from one page to the next.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the $_POST[]; -method to get the data entered in the cart.

Main page: (Mind the id for the field)

```
<div id="cart">
<form method="post" action="anypage.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cart" id=cart value="<?php echo $cart; ?>" />

<h1>Slide Builder</h1>
<ul></ul>
<h2>Drop here to add Slide</h2>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

anypage.php:

```
<? $cart=$_POST['cart']; ?>

<div id="whatever">
<? echo $cart ?>

</div>
```

Of course you can use a session as well, but if you only want to pass
data from one page to an other, this is the simplest way.

Hope you caught up something from this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this, and the "anypage.php" just shows     div id="cart" /div inside the rendered code. The page itself stays white without any passed content.

Comment: What would I put in $_POST on the "anypage.php"? The cart builds the items in a list as they are dropped. How do I write it so it sends the content between the <ul> tags?

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not complete: Chech the "any page.php" now.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the content from fist page in a session var and read the var on the second page. Another way is to read the session var with jquery $.get() and write into your div on second page. Or have i misunderstood you?

Comment: Marcel, that could be possible. I am very new at this and would like to know how I could do it. I simply have to take the user's choice and put that into a 'code' <li>  </li> on the "anypage.php" But for me that's quite the chore!